# OptaPlanner ConstraintProvider

Tags: optaplanner

I have created a small project resolve below usecase

Use Case:

- We have DocYards – which can handle 80/40/20.. containers per hour. DocYards will place containers on Trucks
- We have Trucks – which can Carry 10/20/6.. containers capacity.

**Problem Solution** :
We need to plan which Truck goes to which DocYard at what time, based up on container capacities.

Example:

If DocYard having 40 Capacity
We can send Two Trucks with Capacity 25, 15 (matched or less to DicYard Capacity) at 8:00 - 9:00 timeslot

If DocYard having 10 Capacity
We can only send one Truck with Capacity >10 (matched or less to DicYard Capacity) at 9:00 - 10:00 timeslot

i have created below constraint to solve the problem

```
    Constraint requiredCapacityConstraint(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(Truck.class)
            .groupBy(Truck::getDocYard, Truck::getTruckCapacity)
            .filter((docYard, reqCapacity) -> reqCapacity > docYard.getCapacity())
            .penalize("requiredCapacityTotal",
                    HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                    (docYard, truckCapacity) -> truckCapacity - docYard.getCapacity());
}
```

i got below output , which is wrong - because it is assigning trucks greaterthan its capacity

```text
|            |DocYard-A-40|DocYard-B-20|DocYard-C-10|
|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| 08:00      | T40        | T19        | T10        |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| 09:00      | T15,T30    | T11,T12    | T03        |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| 10:00      | T22        | T20        | T05        |
|------------|------------|------------|------------|
here number after alphabet is CAPACITY of that Truck / DocYard
```

Can someone help me what's wrong & how can i resolve this ?

attching github repo of above problem

[Github Link](https://github.com/smlcodes/OptaPlanner-DocYrd/tree/main/solver)

Comment: Is the capacity for the entire day, or only for a certain timeslot? The groupBy given calculate the requiredCapacity for the entire day, and not for a timeslot. Additionally, I cannot tell what "truckConflict" is supposed to do (has comment "// A DocYard can servce at most one Truck at the same time." but DocYard is not used anywhere in its constraint stream).

Comment: @ChristopherChianelli Capacity is for 1 Hour only, not complete day. Timeslots are like 8-9, 9-10.  I need to send Trucks to docYard having matched Capacity in a given time slot. Actually I'm new to OptaPlanner, Can you suggest code snippet based on above constraints. I have added GitHub link for reference. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is `groupBy(Truck::getDocYard, Truck::getTruckCapacity)` only groups the trucks, not sum them. In addition, it does not take into account the Truck's timeslot. To calculate capacity used during a particular timeslot, a second groupBy key need to be used, along with `ConstraintCollector.sum` to calculate the sum:

```
Constraint requiredCapacityConstraint(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(Truck.class)
        .groupBy(Truck::getDocYard, Truck::getTimeslot, ConstraintCollectors.sum(Truck::getTruckCapacity))
        .filter((docYard, timeslot, reqCapacity) -> reqCapacity > docYard.getCapacity())
        .penalize("requiredCapacityTotal",
                HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                (docYard, timeslot, truckCapacity) -> truckCapacity - docYard.getCapacity());
}
```

Comment: I tried, but DocYard is still taking Trucks with more than its capacity. anyway thanks for your help. @ChristopherChianelli

Comment: I get a valid solution with this constraint (although the first version I posted used `Truck::getCapacity` instead of `Truck::getTruckCapacity`.

Comment: It's working for small data around 10-15 trucks. If we increase Trucks data, once DocYard reached its capacity it should not accept, we need to send tham to unassigned list. How can I add that constraint ?

Comment: See the overconstrained planning section of the OptaPlanner docs: https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/repeated-planning/repeated-planning.html#overconstrainedPlanning ; in summary: Change score to HardMediumSoftScore; and either add a mock DocYard that triggers a medium constraint if used (virtual value) or set both the timeslot and docking station planning variables to nullable and trigger a medium constraint if either of the planning variable of a Truck are null (nullable variables).